# How to return the full path of a file in Python?

Tags: python, path, robotframework

I have this class which accept a whole file as an argument.
And I need to somehow extract the full path of the file

```
    class ATestCase(SuiteRule):
       def apply(self, suitefile):
           suitepath = ???The absolute path of suitefile???
           print(suitepath)
```

The exact type of suitefile is
**<class 'rflint.parser.parser.SuiteFile'>**

Comment: What is the type of `suitefile`?

Comment: `suitefile.name` will give you the path.

Comment: @KrkRamaKrishna, you don't know what type is [expected for] `suitefile` and if it has `name` attribute or what that attribute will be (if exists).

Comment: @buran he said the method is accepting a file so if it is of a file type then it should have a name attribute.

Comment: The exact type of the suitefile is <class 'rflint.parser.parser.SuiteFile'>.
I think it's basically return a whole file.

Comment: @KrkRamaKrishna, with the additional information provided - `name` attribute will return [just the name, without path and without extension](https://github.com/boakley/robotframework-lint/blob/b0619ac58a8b1be125f9c98856a664594614570f/rflint/parser/parser.py#L123). As I expected - even if `name` attribute exists, you don't know what it will yield. Never assume when don't know.

Comment: @ThinhLe, with the additional information provided and looking at the source - `SuiteFile` inherits from `RobotFile`, so [`suitefile.path` will give you the absolute path (incl, file name)](https://github.com/boakley/robotframework-lint/blob/b0619ac58a8b1be125f9c98856a664594614570f/rflint/parser/parser.py#L124).

Comment: Hello @buran,
Your answer solved the problem perfectly.
Can you type in the answer so I can mark you solution as the best one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with the additional information provided (that `suitfile` is class `rflint.parser.parser.SuiteFile` and looking at [the source code](https://github.com/boakley/robotframework-lint/blob/b0619ac58a8b1be125f9c98856a664594614570f/rflint/parser/parser.py#L124) - class `SuiteFile` inherits from class `RobotFile`, so `suitefile.path` will give you the absolute path (incl. the file name).